# Django Template Nested for with If Statement

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a selection box in a HTML table where the given name should be selected in the combo box.  In order to do this, I need to create a nested loop.  The outer loop creates the rows, whereas the inner loop fills the grid cell with options for "Resources".  For this example I'm only showing the code creating the Resource cell.

The nested loop creates the  items, and contains an if statement comparing the action.owner value with the resource.name value.  If the items match, the option value should be selected.  The server runs with the code, and I cannot find any hidden problems.  However I'm not getting the expected results.  No item is being selected.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Note that I have only started learning Django and web development a week ago!

```
{% for action in actions %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <SELECT class="custom-select">

        {% for resource in resources %}

        <option value = "{{resource.name}}" {% if action.owner == resource.name %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{resource.name}}</option>

        {% endfor %}

        </SELECT>
    </td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Some HTML output for a random row that I selected with a dummy html tag to show which action.owner was in question:

> ```
>               <td>
>                   <SELECT class="custom-select">
>
>                       <option value = "None" actionOwnerVal = John >None</option>
>                       <option value = John" actionOwnerVal = John >John</option>
>                       <option value = "Bob" actionOwnerVal = John >Bob</option>
>                   </SELECT>
>                 </td>
> ```

The Actions class:

```
actionChoices = (
    ('New','New'),
    ('In Progress','In Progress'),
    ('Critical','Critical'),
    ('Done','Done')
)


class Actions(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Resources, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = 0)
    closureDate = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500,choices=actionChoices,default='New')
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.task)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Actions"
```

The Resources class:

```
class Resources(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Resources"
```

Comment: I refer you to that great debugging aid: "When in doubt, print it out!" 
Make another similar loop above this one, that just prints `resource.name` and `action.owner`.

Comment: From what I can see the code should produce the result you want. Could you post the HTML that is produced?

Comment: Is `action.owner` a string, or is it some sort of custom user class object?

Comment: A `select` tag shouldn't have a `value` attribute. Though I haven't seen your models, I'm not sure that `action.owner` and `resource.name` could ever be the same thing.

Comment: Rob L, I added that tag for debugging purposes - it does not do anything

Comment: John Gordon, action.owner and resource.name are both strings.  I printer both values as dummy attributes in the html code to make sure of this

Comment: John Gordon, I created dummy html attributes in <options> to make sure the values are what I think they are.  Nothing funny in there

Comment: Show us the class definitions of `action` and `resource`.

Comment: Added class definitions as well as some html output

Comment: As I suspected, `owner` is not a string.  It is a `Resource` object, and that class defines a `__str__` method that returns a string value _when the object is printed_.  I think you might actually want to compare `resource.name` to `action.owner.name`.

Comment: In fact, `resource` and `action.owner` both appear to be `Resource` objects.  Why are you checking the `name` attribute for one but not the other?

Comment: John Gordon, thanks that fixed the problem.  Would have taken me a long time to figure that one out!  My understanding of Django models are not that good so I did not catch that one due to the output looking correct.  Add it as the answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource` and `action.owner` are both `Resource` objects, so you should be comparing `resource.name` to `action.owner.name`.

`action.owner` appeared to be a string value when printed in the template, because its class defines a `__str__` method.